How do I maximize this specific loglikelihood function in R?
I am interested in determining the parameters mu and lambda that maximizes the function:
LogLikelihood_Function <- function(complete_data, censorship_matrix, mu, lambda, subject_index)
Theoretical background
As part of my research, I am interested in calculating the MLE (maximum likelihood estimator) of a multivariate normal distribution in the presence of censored data (left, right or interval censored data). The above mentioned function has the following entries:

The entry complete_data refers to a matrix $n\times p$, where $n$ is the number of observations and $p$ is the dimension of each observed Gaussian random vector (with possible censorship).
The entry censorship_matrix is used to indicate which entries from each observation is censored or not.
The variable mu represents the expected value from the target distribution which we do not know and would like to estimate (but which also need to be explicited as an entry of the likelihood function).
The variable lambda represents the expected value from the target distribution which we do not know and would like to estimate (but which also need to be explicited as an entry of the likelihood function).
Finally, the entry subject_index corresponds to choose the observation from which the marginal likelihood is being constructed.

I have already tried to apply the optim function, but I did not succeed so far.
That being said, I would like to know if anyone could give me some guidance as how to solve this problem.

The optim function expects the function being optimized to accept a vector of parameters as its first argument - as the documentation says, "...
A function to be minimized (or maximized), with first argument the vector of parameters over which minimization is to take place. "
